# appending results from a loop to a data.table with rbindlist()

Tags: r, data.table

I am having trubles appending my results from a for loop into a previously created `data.table`. I am using `rbnindlist` and get an error:

```
Error in rbindlist(policyBacktest2, backtestProducts2, use.names = TRUE,  : 
  idcol must be a logical or character vector of length 1. If logical TRUE the id column will named '.id'.
```

I have used a loop to get some data.

```
  for (policy in policies){
    # procedures
    }
```

to use the `rbindlist` i have converted thee
 placeholder table as well as the resulting table into lists:

```
> results
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
    fromDate1     plan1      region1 noins1  nextplan noinsnext nextvalue   regionnext  fromDate2     plan2 noins2      region2


> placeholder
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
   policyID nextplan noinsnext nextvalue regionnext fromdate1 fromdate2 plan1 plan2 noins1 noins2 region1 region2 value1month12
```

then I used:

```
result <- rbindlist(results, placeholder, use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
```

Why am i getting this error ?

Comment: I don't think `rbindlist` works the way you want it to. I think you need to put both tables in one list and use `rbindlist` to bind those two tables. Not two lists and trying to rbind them together

Answer (score 0):

Try using smartbind from gtools package

```
library(gtools)

dat = do.call(smartbind, results)
```

Hope this will resolve your issue